# Javascript function not defined in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problems with a simple bit of code. I'm trying to take a value from an input field and then do a simple calculation. The calculation is supposed to take place with an `onSubmit` command and then append it to a `p` tag.

**HTML:**

```
<h1 class="titleHead">Calculator</h1>

<form method="POST" action="#" onSubmit="depositCal()">
  <input type="text" name="money" id="money">
  <input type="submit" value="How much" onSubmit="">
</form>

<div>
  <p class="answer"></p>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var numberOne = $('#money').val(),
    numberTwo = 4;

    var finalNumber = numberOne + numberTwo;
    function depositCal() {
        $('.answer').append(finalNumber);
     }
})
```

I get back function not defined when it runs.

I know this is probably very simple but any help would be greatly appreciate.

Comment: Move `depositCal()` function outside of the `$(document).ready(function()`.

Comment: Declare your function outside the `document.ready`. You don't need it there.

Comment: If i do that i get finalNumber is not defined?

Comment: You'll also have to declare the global variables outside too (but assign their values inside) or move it all into the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Give your form a name and ID e.g. 'myForm'

JS

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var numberOne = $('#money').val();
     var numberTwo = 4;
     var finalNumber = numberOne + numberTwo;
     $('.answer').append(finalNumber);
});
```

e.preventDefault() - stops the form from submitting (thus refreshing the page) and the function is only fired when submit is clicked.

**Addition**

numberOne is getting it's value from a form field so it sees it as a string.
To prevent this use this line instead:

```
var numberOne = parseFloat($('#money').val());
```

Which forces the value to be a (float) number.

Comment: Sidenote: If the Form should be submitted or the Data should be transfered elsewhere, it can be extended with `$('myForm').submit()` or an ajax-call after the calculation

Comment: So this works but its placing numberOne and numberTwo side by side and not adding them together?

Comment: parseFloat did it thanks everyone for your help. I'll get the hang of all this one day :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the function in global scope if you want to use it in inline js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var numberOne = $('#money').val(),
        numberTwo = 4;
    var finalNumber = numberOne + numberTwo;
})
function depositCal() {
    $('.answer').append($('#money').val() + 4);
}
```

You could also make it a global function by attaching the `function` to `window` object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need `$(document).ready` here and do calculation of `finalNumber` inside function so that it will give you the correct value of `money` input, otherwise you will get `NaN` or empty value-

```
function depositCal() {
    var numberOne = $('#money').val(),
        numberTwo = 4;
    var finalNumber = numberOne + numberTwo;
    $('.answer').append(finalNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep the **depositCal** function definition out of  `$(document).ready()`,because first the whole document is loaded,then `$(document).ready()` is called.So while loading the form,browser finds **depositCal** as **undefined** as it is defined after document is **fully loaded**......So keep the depositCal definition in global scope